# Format date on Grid Panel not works, strange ..!

Tags: extjs, store, datefield

I have a gridPanel with CellEditing plugins .. !

I use datefield with renderer :  **Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y/m/d')**
The good format is dysplay , but when i get model from my grid , i have another format ...

My datefield definition :

```
header : 'Start Date',
                dataIndex : 'start_date',
                id : 'Start_Dategridid',

                 flex : 2,
            //renderer: formatDate,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y/m/d'),



                field : {

                    xtype : 'datefield',
    anchor : '20%',

     itemId: 'Start_Date',
    disabledDays : [0,6],
    altFormats: 'Y/m/d',
    format : 'Y/m/d',
    editable: false,
    value : '""',


                     allowBlank : true 
                }
```

When i retrieve model with :

```
var model =  mystore.getAt(0);
model.get('start_date'); // I have "Wed Jul 20 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CET)"
```

So, my application can't works .. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you use get method to retrieve a value - you'll receive a fully parsed date value, this is not what is showed in the grid. After you received a value from the model - you can format it as you like.

E.g.:

```
console.log(Ext.Date.format(model.get('start_date'), Ext.Date.patterns.ShortDate));
```

You can check this link: [Extjs Date](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.Date)

Comment: Oh ! :/ I would like send model.data on my server ! I must use regExp to replace (model.get('start_date') by Ext.Date.format(model.get('start_date') ?!